# How do I tell the element count of array declared as: std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have this variable declaration:

```
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> data;
```

How do I tell the element count if this array is given to me?

Comment: If that's all you have …. you can't.

Comment: You don't. If you need that, use `std::vector` (or store the size in a separate variable).

Comment: I thought it's tricky. This variable is a return value and it's all I've got. I'll have to work-around it.

Comment: As a workaround, return `std::pair<std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>, std::size_t>`.

Comment: What is this return value representing?  Do you know if there is a null terminator (a zero) at the end of the data?

Comment: Actually it's a png image data. It's a library function (I can't change it) which returns a class with this variable plus width/height. However I don't know what is the data size of the point. Well, I think I'll figure it out somehow. Good start is that only this variable gives me no clue about the size so I have to improvise ;-)

Comment: Read the library docs/examples. I suspect that the size is simply `width * height`

Answer (score 0):

As explained by guys in comments (thanks) this is not possible.
It's just a pointer without any information about the size of the array which is pointing to.